# Left join postgresql with condition null

Tags: postgresql, left-join

Hello everyone i'm using postgresql-13, i'm stuck in this and tried but still not getting the result i wanted:

```
TABLE_A
ID|SEQ|Name
1|7|Dash
2|8|Goo

TABLE_B
REF_ID|Country
1|India
3|England

TABLE_C
SEQ|Country
7|America
8|Denmark
```

So i wanted to do a left join from TABLE_A to get the country in the TABLE_B, but if the Country can't be found in the TABLE_B i join to TABLE_C
So Dash will have Country of INDIA since it can be found in the TABLE_B even if you join the SEQ to TABLE_C it should be America, but we can find "Dash" ID in the TABLE_B so we take the country from TABLE_B. For "Goo", he should have a country DENMARK since "Goo" ID can't be found in the TABLE_B.

So basically left join would be

```
Select a.name,
case when b.country is null then c.country
when b.country is not null then b.country
end country_name
from TABLE_A a
left join TABLE_B b on a.ID=b.REF_ID
left join TABLE_C c on a.SEQ=c.Country
```

Is that the right query?

Answer (score 0):

The key between table_a and table_c is wrong. You must replace `c.country` by `c.seq`.Your query should be

```
Select a.name,
case when b.country is null then c.country else b.country end country_name
from TABLE_A a
left join TABLE_B b on a.ID=b.REF_ID
left join TABLE_C c on a.SEQ=c.seq
```